# Passing a string from one viewcontroller to another Tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, string, viewcontroller

I have a string data that has to be sent to another viewcontroller - In my case is a tabbarcontroller. I received a null data while sending. 
Below is the code snippet:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController2;

@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController{

@private
ViewController2 *suiteNo;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) ViewController2 *viewController2;


-(IBAction)suiteNumber:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

I have declared in the .m file as below

ViewController1.m

```
@synthesize viewController2;

//data accessed
self.viewController2.suiteNum = [[sender titleLabel] text];
```

ViewController2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController{

NSString *suiteNum;

  }

 @property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *suiteNum;
 @end
```

ViewController2.m

```
@synthesize suiteNum;

//the passed string is used here
NSString *firstURL = [segmentOneURL stringByAppendingString:suiteNum];
```

Is there any place where i made a mistake? Please correct me if im wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making suiteNum property  in viewcontroller2 ,declare suiteNum in appdelegate and copy the string value from viewcontroller1  to suiteNum

like this:=
AppDelegate *appdelegate1= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appdelegate1.suiteNum= [[sender titleLabel] text];

and when viewcontroller2 appears override it's viewwillappear delegate as

AppDelegate *appdelegate1= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSString *firstURL=appdelegate1.suiteNum;

Comment: I tried defining suiteNum property in the appdelegate and then import the .h file of the appdelegate. 
Do i have to change the @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *suiteNum; to something else?

Comment: whenever u access suiteNum always use this line before =appdelegate *appdelegate1= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; and then use appdelegate1.suitNum = [[sender titleLabel] text]; and then in the ViewController2 again make appdelegate instance as above and then NSString *firstURL=appdelegate1.suiteNum;

Comment: Thanks piyush. Is it possible to edit and add this in ur answer? Seems a bit difficult read the syntax. Thank you